# PHP preg_split between Character (prefix) and Number

Tags: php, preg-split

Sorry for my bad English, I would to ask about How to split characters and numbers using preg_split(). For example, I have any data with prefix like :

```
ABC00001 to array(0 => 'ABC', 1 => 00001)
DEFG00002 to array(0 => 'DEFG', 1 => 00002)
AB00003 to array(0 => 'AB', 1 => 00003)
```

Thanks for advise

Answer (score 2):

Split on the zero-length position that follows the sequence of letters.

Code: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/D4MZb)

```
$string = 'ABC00001';
$output = preg_split('~[A-Z]+\K~', $string);
var_export($output);
```

The `\K` says forget the previous matched characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` and `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flags to do what you want:

```
$string = 'ABC00001';
$output = preg_split('/([A-Z]+)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => ABC [1] => 00001 )
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/cfCvF)